# Multiple chunks in a tab

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want chunks of Example1 and Example2 in a single tab and Example3 in another tab. The code below is showing everything in one tab. In my desired output, some chunks in sectionA tab and some in sectionB tab.

```````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    code_folding: show
    theme: united
    highlight: tango
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ## and ###)
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(rmarkdown) #used for syntax highlighting in this document
```

## Sections {.tabset}

### Section A

# Example1
```{r, eval=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
<details>
  <summary>Click for Output</summary>
    ```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
    plot(cars)
    ```
</details> 

### Section B

# Example2
```{r}
quantile(mtcars$mpg, probs = c(0.99))
```
## {-}

# Example3
```{r table}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5,, 1:5], caption = "A table caption")
``````
```````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something along these lines? Once you start a tabbed section, you can't willy-nilly throw around subsections but should follow specific hierarchy. If you have a tabbed section of level `##`, everything under level `###` will become a tab. Anything deeper than that will become a title in the said tab.

```````
## Sections {.tabset}

### Section A

#### Example1
```{r, eval=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
<details>
  <summary>Click for Output</summary>
    ```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
    plot(cars)
    ```
</details> 


#### Example2
```{r}
quantile(mtcars$mpg, probs = c(0.99))
```

### Section B
#### Example3
```{r table}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5,, 1:5], caption = "A table caption")
``````
```````

[image]

Comment: It works but TOC stopped working because of this. In TOC, SectionA should have two sub options, SectionB should have one sub option

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari that sounds like you need a solution that would require some hacking, sorry. :(